# Why is cmake not mocing my Q_OBJECT headers?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, qtquick2, moc

I currently have a project set up like this:

```
- project/
--- include/
--- src/
--- qml/
--- CMakeLists.txt
--- qml.qrc
```

And a `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0071 NEW)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${QtQml_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS} ${QtQml_DEFINITIONS} ${${Qt5Quick_DEFINITIONS}})

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(wormhole_qt)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick Qml OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5QuickCompiler)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

MACRO(HEADER_DIRECTORIES sub_dir return_list)
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE new_list ${sub_dir}/*.h)
    SET(dir_list "")
    FOREACH(file_path ${new_list})
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(dir_path ${file_path} PATH)
        SET(dir_list ${dir_list} ${dir_path})
    ENDFOREACH()
    LIST(REMOVE_DUPLICATES dir_list)
    SET(${return_list} ${dir_list})
ENDMACRO()

HEADER_DIRECTORIES(include mylist)
include_directories(include)
include_directories(lib)
include_directories(${mylist})

file(GLOB INCLUDES *.h)
file(GLOB_RECURSE CPP_FILES src/*.cpp)

qtquick_compiler_add_resources(QT_RESOURCES qml.qrc)
qt5_wrap_cpp(MOC_SOURCE ${INCLUDES})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE ${MOC_SOURCE} ${CPP_FILES} ${QT_RESOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Quick Core Qml OpenGL)
```

The problem is that in the actual build step, moc doesn't find any of my headers that have `Q_OBJECT` decalred in them. I can tell because this is what my build looks like:

```
14:18:45: Running steps for project wormhole_qt...
14:18:45: Starting: "/usr/local/bin/cmake" --build . --target all
[  1%] Generating qmlcache_loader.cpp
[  2%] Generating qml_Empty_qml.cpp
[  4%] Generating qml_Style_qml.cpp
[  5%] Generating qml_main_qml.cpp
[  7%] Generating qml_setup_NewProject_qml.cpp
[  8%] Generating qml_setup_Setup_qml.cpp
[  9%] Generating qml_setup_Startup_qml.cpp
[ 11%] Generating qml_workspace_AnimationWindow_qml.cpp
[ 12%] Generating qml_workspace_DepthChartControls_qml.cpp
[ 14%] Generating qml_workspace_NewAnimationWindow_qml.cpp
[ 15%] Generating qml_workspace_TraceWindow_qml.cpp
[ 16%] Generating qml_workspace_WorkspaceMenuBar_qml.cpp
[ 18%] Generating qml_workspace_Workspace_qml.cpp
[ 19%] Automatic MOC for target wormhole_qt
[ 19%] Built target wormhole_qt_autogen
[ 21%] Generating qrc_qml_qmlcache.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target wormhole_qt
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wormhole_qt.dir/src/controllers/AnimationsController.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wormhole_qt.dir/src/controllers/ApplicationController.cpp.o
```

If you look where it says 19%, it says that it is automatically moccing, but it doesn't list any files, which means it isn't finding any. In addition, because of the moccing not occurring, there is a linking error because the signals don't exist. Am I missing something in my `CMakeLists.txt`, or do I need to change up the structure of my project? How do I make MOC find my header files?

Comment: Rewriting this comment because the edit window passed: Verify the content of `${INCLUDES}` with a `message(...)` call. Furthermore, the `qt5_wrap_cpp` should not be there if AUTOMOC functions correctly. Can you show an example of a header (with `Q_OBJECT`) and cpp file pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AUTOMOC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) property tells CMake to scan the header files and generate moc commands if necessary. If CMake doesn't know about the header file it won't scan it. So all you need to do is to pass the headers along with the sources to `add_executable` function.

After that remove the `qt5_wrap_cpp` function. You don't need as long as you're using `AUTOMOC`.

And remove the `qt5_use_modules` function. Modern CMake can do all of this for you with plain [`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5Quick Qt5Core Qt5Qml Qt5OpenGL)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/target_link_libraries.html)

Comment: "pass the headers along with the sources to `add_executable`": When there is a `.cpp` file with a corresponding `.h` file, then passing only the `.cpp` is fine and MOC will know. But for the case of having lone `.h` files with enums, structs or similar, the `.h` *must* be passed here!