# Undefined reference to MasterController::StaticMetaObject

Tags: c++, qt

I'm just starting learning Qt and currently I'm reading the book ***Learn Qt 5 by Nicolas Sheriff***. Where I am, in chapter 2, I'm following all the instructions and I'M understanding what I am doing but i getting stuck on one thing: when i compile the following program along with others, I'm getting this list of errors:[image shwowing the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg4Bm.png)

Here's the [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eTsD.png)

and the files I find worth showing are:

***cm.pro file***

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = cm-lib
TEMPLATE = lib

CONFIG += c++17
DEFINES += CMLIB_LIBRARY
INCLUDEPATH += source

SOURCES += source/models/client.cpp \
           source/controllers/master-controller.cpp \

HEADERS += source/cm-lib_global.h \
           source/controllers/master-controller.h \
           source/models/client.h \
```

***cm-lib.pro***

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = cm-lib
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += c++17
DEFINES += CMLIB_LIBRARY
INCLUDEPATH += source

SOURCES += source/models/client.cpp \
           source/controllers/master-controller.cpp \

HEADERS += source/cm-lib_global.h \
           source/controllers/master-controller.h \
           source/models/client.h \
```

***cm-ui.pro***

```
QT += qml quick

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++17
INCLUDEPATH += source \
        ../cm-lib/source

SOURCES += source/main.cpp

RESOURCES += views.qrc
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../build-cm-kit1-Debug/cm-lib/ -lcm-lib
```

***MasterController.h***

```
#ifndef MASTERCONTROLLER_H
#define MASTERCONTROLLER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <cm-lib_global.h>

namespace cm::controllers {
class CMLIBSHARED_EXPORT MasterController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QString welcomeMessage = "This is MasterController to Major Tom";
    Q_PROPERTY( QString ui_welcomeMessage MEMBER welcomeMessage CONSTANT )
    public:
    explicit MasterController(QObject* parent = nullptr);
};
}
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <controllers/master-controller.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    #endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<cm::controllers::MasterController>("CM", 1, 0, "MasterController");

    cm::controllers::MasterController masterController{};

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine{};
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("masterController", &masterController);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/views/MasterView.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

It' long like that because I used the MVC design pattern here like in the book.

I think the problem is caused by the inclusion of the Q_OBJECT macro in `MasterController.h` because when I remove it, the project compile well without any issue.

After googling about the issue, on almost all the places I visited, the error was caused by the fact that the classes including Q_OBJECT macro would be declared in their own header file or `qmake` was not rerunned on these files including Q_OBJECT but It's not true in my case.

System tools used:

- Qt creator
- Qt 5.11
  -Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: An amazing alternative to the `.pro` files is the `.qbs` model. It is a lot more verbose and straight forward when it comes to setting these things up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The undefined reference is most likely caused by a missing moc file. When subclassing a qt object and using the Q_OBJECT macro the Qt Meta-Object Compiler creates a moc file (moc_master-controller.cpp) containing qobject related definitions including the missing `staticMetaObject`. This source file has to be compiled with the class definition. This is done automatically when using qmake.

Based on the code you provided your setup should be working. A few things to try:

- Run qmake again. After adding or removing the Q_OBJECT macro qmake has to be run again. If you added Q_OBJECT *after* running qmake then the makefile does not contain the moc command for master-controller.h.
- Make sure that the class is exported correctly from the lib and the other project finds the lib and imports correctly.
- It is worth a try to do a clean and rebuild in case there was a problem during a previous build.

I tried reproducing the issue based on the code you provided but it compiled fine for me. In case you want to cross-reference with your code I've included mine below.

**cm-lib.pro**

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = cm-lib
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += c++17
DEFINES += CMLIB_LIBRARY
INCLUDEPATH += source

SOURCES += master-controller.cpp

HEADERS += cm-lib_global.h \
    master-controller.h
```

**cm-lib_global.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>

#if defined(CMLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define CMLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define CMLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

**master-controller.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <cm-lib_global.h>

namespace cm::controllers {
class CMLIBSHARED_EXPORT MasterController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QString welcomeMessage = "This is MasterController to Major Tom";
    Q_PROPERTY( QString ui_welcomeMessage MEMBER welcomeMessage CONSTANT )
    public:
    explicit MasterController(QObject* parent = nullptr);
};
}
```

**master-controller.cpp**

```
#include "master-controller.h"

cm::controllers::MasterController::MasterController(QObject* parent):
    QObject(parent)
{
}
```

**cm-ui.pro**

```
QT += qml quick

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++17
INCLUDEPATH += ../cm-lib

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -L"../build-cm-lib-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug" -lcm-lib
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <master-controller.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    #endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<cm::controllers::MasterController>("CM", 1, 0, "MasterController");

    cm::controllers::MasterController masterController{};

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine{};
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("masterController", &masterController);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/views/MasterView.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: "The undefined reference is most likely caused by a missing moc file.": Exactly. And for some more reasons how that can happen, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413341).

Comment: Note that qmake frequently will report "nothing to do". When that happens, I close the project, remove the build directory, then open the project again. qmake definitely finds something to do under those conditions.

Comment: Your comment "Run qmake again. After adding or removing the Q_OBJECT macro qmake has to be run again" saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change MEMBER to READ in the Q_PROPERTY solved this problem 
for me tho.

Took me hours :) You're welcome.

***MasterController.h***

```qt
    #ifndef MASTERCONTROLLER_H
    #define MASTERCONTROLLER_H
    #include <QObject>
    #include <QString>
    #include <cm-lib_global.h>

    namespace cm::controllers {
    class CMLIBSHARED_EXPORT MasterController : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        QString welcomeMessage = "This is MasterController to Major Tom";
        Q_PROPERTY( QString ui_welcomeMessage READ welcomeMessage CONSTANT ) //<-----MEMBER to READ
        public:
        explicit MasterController(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    };
    }
```

*Btw.: In the error message (of the screenshot you included in the question) you can right click and expand the message `Show Output` in the qt creator. Normally the error has a zickzackely underlining in there.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself is OK and compiles, but you're missing a library in **linking**.

That's because you `#include <QGuiApplication>`, but you removed gui in thos line in your .pro:

```
QT       -= gui
```

Solution:

```
QT       += gui <and any other libraries you've used, e.g. bluetooth>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error for QWebSocketServer class.

was fixed by adding following line to .pro file

`QT += websockets`